# YADCF and SharePoint 2010

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, datatables, yadcf

I want to perform mult-select AND filtering of individual choices in a JSON array.

```
Data:
Row 0: [Cats, Dogs]
Row 1: [Cats]
Row 2: [Cats, Birds, Dogs]
Filter selection: Cats and Dogs.
Result: Display Rows 0 and 2.
```

But my code results in OR filtering.  Also, the filter selection choices are the entire contents of each row.  So the rows in the picker look like:

```
Cats, Dogs
Cats
Cats, Dogs, Birds
```

When they should look like:

```
Cats
Dogs
Birds
```

Here is the code:

```
var call = $.ajax({
                    url: "https://.../_vti_bin/listdata.svc/DocLib?$expand=Classification",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    headers: {Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"}
                });

    call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){

            myData = data.d.results;
            var dtTable = $('#example').DataTable({
            data: myData,
            columns:[
                {data: "Classification.results[, ].Value"}
                ],
            stateSave: true
            });

            yadcf.init(dtTable, [
                    {column_number:0,
                    filter_type: "multi_select"                     
                    }]);
            });
```

Comment: I don't see any yadcf related code in your question? what have you tried so far? and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Hi Daniel.  I cleaned up the question.  Thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: You will have to use the `filter_type: 'multi_select_custom_func'`, see the [following jsfiddle sample with complete solution](http://jsfiddle.net/wkwhmcb1/137/)